# Why one would use array in functional programming (erlang) instead of lists?

Tags: erlang, erlang-stdlib

when you are going to use array module - and when to use arrays generally in functional programming - erlang in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rationale is that if you do want a *functional* (nondestructive) data structure using integer keys, then the array module is significantly more efficient than a dict, gb_tree or similar (which can use any kinds of values as keys). And the indexing is zero-based because that's generally more useful for the kind of problems you'd want an array for.

I find the note in Learn You Some Erlang to be quite off the mark.

Comment: I agree with LYSE about indexing. Having **both** 0-indexing **and** 1-indexing is the worse than having either of them and the 1-indexing was used first in Erlang. I can add/subtract 1.

Comment: You're definitely right, deleted my post. Here is the LYSE note, for reference: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#arrays